# How to force release an UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, autorelease

Is there a way to force a custom UITableViewCell to be released instead of waiting for the OS to autorelease it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you thought of this, but sending it a release message would do the trick... When do you want to force this release?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I believe release an object that has been autoreleased before will crash the application. The reason for releasing the UITableViewCell is just to free the resource of a complex custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can only add autoreleased cells to them and 'wait' for the OS to release them, but isn't this nearly instant after they left the screen? Talking from experience here, not from knowledge, so you better check ;-).